# ECS Fargate / single ALB / multiple docker containers

Tags: docker, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-fargate

Does anyone have an example of how I could build up an ECS cluster with a single application load balancer forwarding host header request to two different docker containers.

I want to have one ALB for A single ESC cluster running both my angular site as well as a.net web service. Ultimately my goal is to script this in terraform.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have created the ALB and added a listener for 80 and 443.   I than created a ESC cluster with an service/task for each container. I added a listener rule that forwards to individual target groups. Each target group was on its own port (3000, and 3001).  Does each docker container need to be listening on that port?

Comment: It would be useful if you edited your question to show a [mcve] of what you have tried and if you get an error also include the error. If it doesn't error but doesn't do what you want it to do then explain what it is doing and how you need it to be different.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing all the information I think that you are looking for path-based routing or even better host-based routing.

#### Terraform

You need an **aws_lb_listener_rule** (Load Balancer Listener Rule) for each host/path.
You need an **aws_alb_target_group** for each ECS services and you refer the correct target group inside the resource aws_lb_listener_rule.

#### General

Listener Rules

> Before you start using your Application Load Balancer, you must add one or more listeners. A listener is a process that checks for connection requests, using the protocol and port that you configure. The rules that you define for a listener determine how the load balancer routes request to the targets in one or more target groups. [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html#listener-rules)

Use Path-Based Routing with Your Application Load Balancer

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/tutorial-load-balancer-routing.html

### Examples

#### Host Based Listener Rule

```
resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "host_based_routing" {
  listener_arn = aws_lb_listener.front_end.arn
  priority     = 99

  action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.static.arn
  }

  condition {
    field  = "host-header"
    values = ["my-service.*.terraform.io"]
  }
}
```

Where the conditions block define the host or the pattern (example below) where request must be sent.

#### Path Based Listener Rule

```
resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "static" {
  listener_arn = aws_lb_listener.front_end.arn
  priority     = 100

  action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.static.arn
  }

  condition {
    field  = "path-pattern"
    values = ["/static/*"]
  }
}
```

#### Target group

```
resource "aws_alb_target_group" "alb_target_group" {
  name                 = "example-target-group"
  protocol             = "HTTP"
  port                 = var.exposed_port
  vpc_id               = var.vpc_id
  deregistration_delay = 30
  health_check {
    path    = var.service_health_check_path
    matcher = "200-399"
  }
}
```

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lb_listener_rule.html
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lb_target_group.html